# Supply and demand law from game theory

Tags: game-theory

I am trying to retrive the law of supply and demand from game theory. I don't understand the result.

Suppose we have a probability $p$ to sell a good at price $q$.
I can calculate $p$ as the fraction of people $N(t)$ who will buy the good at the price $q$ over the whole number of people who can buy $N_0$ (the size of market) as

$$
p=\frac{N(q)}{N_0}
$$

if the probability $p$ depends only on price difference, then

$$N(q)=N_0 e^{-\frac{q}{\theta}}$$

where $\theta$ is a parameter and rapresent the elasticity of the demand. So we have that

$$
p=e^{-\frac{q}{\theta}}
$$

The expected value of selling a good at price $q$ is

$$
EV=qe^{-\frac{q}{\theta}} -c
$$
where $c$ is the cost of good.

Now I differentiate respect $q$ and solve the condition $\frac{\partial EV}{\partial q}=0$ and I find that

$$
q=\theta
$$

I can understand that the optimal price to sell is not related to the cost of good, but why I have no relation with the $N_0$?
Why the optimal price does not depend of the size of market $N_0$?

Comment: @OP: I would change the tag. There is no game theory here.

Comment: @OP: For the intuition, I would focus on the extreme cases of perfectly elastic and perfectly inelastic demand curves. In both cases it is fairly obvious that it does not really matter the size of the market.

Comment: For more intuition, you might want to try a linear demand curve, such as $N_0(a-bq)$.